# Wrapping ObservableCollection<T> in C#

Tags: c#, observablecollection, containment

[I have reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8349682/complex-type-ignored-by-entity-framework-code-first) to wrap an instance of `ObservableCollection<T>` in another type.

I'm implementing `ICollection<T>` in my new type.  That's straightforward.  I'm also implementing `INotifyCollectionChanged`, which means implementing

```
public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
```

The best path I can think of to implement this is to place additional code in my implementation of `ICollection<T>`, like this:

```
public void Add(T item)
{
    Collection.Add(item);
    if (CollectionChanged != null) CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, item));
}
```

(Collection is the instance of `ObservableCollection<T>` that I am wrapping).

Is there a way to leverage the implementation of `INotifyCollectionChanged` that Collection provides, rather than re-implementing it myself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  When you assign the value of your `Collection` property or field, handle *its* CollectionChanged event:

```
Collection = new ObservableCollection<T>();
Collection.CollectionChanged += this.HandleCollectionChanged;
```

Then in the HandleCollectionChanged method, you raise the object's own CollectionChanged event.