# Entity Framework Code First and Classes that Implement IList<T>

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I have a `ComplexType` that must implement `IList<T>` ([background info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8349682/complex-type-ignored-by-entity-framework-code-first)).

Unfortunately, Entity Framework complains about the indexed property required of that interface

```
[NotMapped]
public T this[int index]
```

(Note it's decorated with the `NotMapped` data annotation).

I get a `DbUpdateException` at runtime with the inner exception

> Indexed properties are not supported.

If I comment out that the class implements `IList<T>` and comment out the indexed property, instances of the class persist as expected.

Is there some way for a complex type to implement `IList<T>` to be persisted by Entity Framework Code First?

Comment: I changed tag to EFv4.1 because EFv4.2 is just bug fixing of 4.1 and it doesn't need separate tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity framework doesn't support open generic entities and I believe the same is true for complex types. The only way is to define specific type derived from closed generic type as you shown in your linked question.

Also there is some well known bug that mapped class must not have indexer.