# Need Entity Framework to ignore a model member

Tags: c#, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

We need to store a list of data we pull from another table that relates to one of our models. (We are too deep into build to add this relationship to our DB where it should be.) When we attempt to load this list in a property of the model that needs it.

We load this list into a dropdown in a view. The error occurs trying to load this list into the model in the controller. The true caveat is that we have a unique dropdown list for each record in our table in the view.

Our Class:

```
Public class OurModel
  public property ID As Integer
  Public property First As Integer
  Public property Last As Integer
  Public property myList As List(Of SelectListItem)//This is our problem member
End class
```

Controller:

```
                         //This ViewModel is what we pass around from page to page to populate the various elements we need that is not tied to a specific model
Public Function LoadList(myViewModel As ViewModel) As Action Result
   Using db //our database resource 
    For i As Integer = 0 to myViewModel.OurModel
       //Assume table select statement previously declared and initialized into dbGet
       **NOTE: dbGet is retieving data from a different table that is tied to this Model**
       dbGet = dbGet.Where(Function(x) x.ID = myViewModel.OurModel.ID)
       myViewModel.OurModel.myList = dbGet.ToList().[Select](Function(x) New SelectListItem() With {.Value = x.number, .Text = x.number})//ERROR IS HERE
    Next
   End Using
End Function
```

Error:

**LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'DB.ModelTable get_Item(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.**

**UPDATE:** The issue appears to be that LINQ is trying to do something with a the DBContext of a query I do previously in this controller. The error is referencing `DB.Employee` not `DB.Position` which is what I am querying.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up having to write new classes that connected to the database outside of Entity Framework. If you want to use Entity Framework, make sure you database design is PERFECT before you begin building your application and good luck.

Answer (score 3):

I have done almost nothing in VB.Net, but it sounds like get_Item(Int32) may be the same as an indexer in C#.

There's a well-known shortcoming that Entity Framework does not support classes that contain an indexer (even if you decorate that property with `NotMapped`).

I was faced with a similar issue, which was to implement a lockable ObservableCollection.  I found that I could not implement `IList<T>` due to the [indexer issue in EF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8351303/entity-framework-code-first-and-classes-that-implement-ilistt), but that I could implement `ICollection<T>`.

[Lock / Unlock ObservableCollection<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9013060/lock-unlock-observablecollectiont/9013479#9013479)

If you can replace the semantics of a list with those of a collection, that should solve this problem.

Comment: When we put this into our Model, we got the same error. I don't think we can put this into our view model because since its not "indexable" we can't associate it with a particular instance in our List of Models.

Comment: We get the same error if we try to store this in our ViewModel or the ViewBag. EF does not like the list of lists concept.