# Entity Framework complextypes

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have something like:

```
public class Discount {
     public int Id {get;set;}
     public Duration<int> Duration {get;set;}
}

public class Duration<T> {
   public T From {get;set;}
  public T To {get;set;}

}
```

And in the DbContext

```
///
public DbSet<Discount> Discounts {get;set;}
///
```

When I map it to a database via EF the "Duration" class/properties do not appear. Neither as table and nor as a complex type. What could be done?

Comment: Two property "Form" and "To" is of table Discount, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Complex Type Ignored by Entity Framework Code First](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8349682/complex-type-ignored-by-entity-framework-code-first)

Comment: Entity framework does not support generic classes, you need to have them strongly typed. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8349682/complex-type-ignored-by-entity-framework-code-first