# EF Fluent Mapping - map a collection field from another table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6.1

This may already have been asked somewhere, but I can't find a question exactly matching what I'm trying to do.

At the database level, I have TableB which has only two fields - a foreign key to TableA and a nvarchar(max) Code field. The relationship from TableA to TableB is **one-to-many**.

At the EF level, I would like to skip mapping TableB at all. TableA would look like this:

```
public class TableA
{
    public ICollection<string> BCodes {get; set;}
}
```

I would like BCodes to be populated from the Code field of all of the related TableB entities. I know I could accomplish this using views and other hacks on the database, but that destroys the separation of concerns. Is this possible using EF, or do I have to map a TableB entity with just the one string property?

**Update**
I should clarify that this can be a read-only collection for my specific case. Other people who stumble across this question may have different needs, so if you have ideas of a read/write way to implement it, that would be great too.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why don't you want the mapping?

Comment: I'm mostly trying to separate my database implementation details from my entity implementation. At the database level, I need TableB to be in a separate table because it's a one-to-many, but that shouldn't really bleed into my entities. As far as C# is concerned, those codes are just an attribute of TableA.

Comment: But in this case you either have a collection of `TableB` or a collection of `string`. Does it really make any difference?

Comment: Implementation-wise, no, but design wise it's a fundamental difference. TableB isn't a real entity with any sort of meaning in my application. It has no responsibilities and doesn't represent anything concrete. It's basically just a leaky abstraction of database implementation details bleeding into code, which is what POCOs in EF w/ fluent mapping are supposed to prevent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least up to EF 6.1, it's not possible to define primitive type collections (for example a collection of strings). It must be done indirectly.

The best approach I've ever seen is [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8334616/entity-framework-code-first-and-collections-of-primitive-types#8338393).

Alternatively you could use NHibernate, that support this functionality. For example, [you can see this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15475566/fluentnhibernate-and-primitive-type-collection).